# how php does all data transfer with server using SSL after login?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp

i have a requirement like, when i login then my url should be change 'http://' to 'https://'. all the data tranfer should be via SSL. how to do that?
thanks..

Comment: Why not the login form? Shouldn't username and password be over SSL too?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your user to `https://` protocol.

Check this from php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#100877

Answer (score 0):

have your login form submit to a https address... also make sure you have installed an SSL certificate on your server first.